# Parsing excel string to python

Tags: python, excel, data-formats

I would like to store a string value in excel, e.g. ['1','2'], and parse it in python to use as a calculation array. Python accepts this value as string but when I tried to convert the value to int or float, I run into an value error message saying that python can't convert to string to float

Input from Excel `['1','2','3']`
Desired output in python `['1','2','3']`

Problem: When I parse the input, python recognizes as a string "['1','2']" and I can not convert it to the desired output:

example for code:

```
s = "['1','2','3']"
for i in range(1,3)
    print 1 + float(s[i])
```

Comment: Please add the code you have so far to your question.

Comment: Please specify (a) sample input, (b) desired output, (c) actual output, (d) steps taken so far, (e) complete error message. "An value error message" doesn't help at all.

Comment: How does your excel data arrive in your python script?

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you're looking for:

```
s="['1','2','3']"
nums = [float(num[1:-1]) for num in s[1:-1].split(',')]

[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

Note that this assumes A LOT about the cleanliness of your input

This also works, although `eval` is usually avoided unless you absolutely trust your data source.

```
nums = [float(num) for num in eval(s)]
```

Comment: You could use a JSON parser here, because JSON happens to handle lists the same way Python does. If he trusts his scource, I'd rather use eval, though

Comment: Nice idea, but I don't know if it's possible to parse just an array using the `json` module. `json.loads(s)` gives an error: `No JSON object could be decoded`. I believe JSON has to contain an *object* or else it's not valid JSON. `json.loads('{"arr":' + s.replace("'", '"') + '}')['arr']` converts a serialized list into a Python list of strings using the `json` module, but at that point you're making your life more difficult rather than easier. :P